# Angular Cookies

Tags: angular, cookies

Estoy creando un proyecto web con Angular, y tengo un problema a la hora de intentar hacer desaparecer el banner de cookies.

Mi intención era que, al pulsar en: aceptar cookies, se creara una cookie en el navegador y desapareciera el banner. Hasta ahí bien. La cosa es que ahora, al recargar la página, quería que el banner siguiera sin aparecer (ya que la cookie está creada).
Pero no se por que, creo que el problema está en la ternaria que no me modifica el valor de la propiedad.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Este sería mi HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este el código typescript de mi componente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola, si perdona no se habrá cargado el código que intentaba publicar.